# Can we make ASP.NET MVC project to compile on-the-fly just like ASP.NET 2.0?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc

I really love ASP.NET 2.0 for being able to make code-behind changes without neededing to re-compile project.

Now I have moved to ASP.NET MVC but one thing that bother me is the fact that I need to re-compile everytime I make a change in the Controller code.

How can I make my ASP.NET MVC application to compile on-demand like ASP.NET 2.0 project?

Comment: Can you tell us why this is a requirement as generally speaking any changes to a production system should go through propper testing and staging environments and not allow (changes on the fly)

Comment: Basically it will be more productive for us to work with the ASP.NET 2.0 model. We can worry about compiling when we put the site to the production, as opposed to needing to compile everytime while we are still developing.

Comment: Unless you're compiling a monolithic application, compile times should be minimal.  Also if you make a breaking change, how do you know 12 other pages aren't affected?  The Web Application model was removed when 2.0 debuted...it was quickly brought back because of shortfalls with website projects like this.  I agree with @griegs - you should re-evaluate why you're using this model, with any modern computer you'll have a hard time finding it more productive.

Comment: @Nick, I'm with you.  You need to be aware that your changes potentially affect other areas of the application that others are working on and i think compile on the fly is a dangerous thing.  Compile times, even on a large application, are in the seconds and shouldn't be an issue.  Also I think better debugging techniques might help here.  Then again @henreman might be running on a 386!

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't bother much about this. One of the greatest advantages of ASP.NET MVC over traditional WebForms is that it allows you to separate concerns and have unit tests. So you make a change in the controller and navigate to the corresponding unit test to verify it. [Red-Green-Refactor](http://jamesshore.com/Blog/Red-Green-Refactor.html) cycle.